# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. DataRow dRow2 = ds2.Tables["own"].Rows[0];?/?

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to call a specific row from a table and keep getting error, anyone have any help?
My Database has 2 rows atm with 5 columns with values filled

Comment: have you debugged your code..? try passing the DataSet `ds` into the Navigate record as a parameter like so `private void NavigateRecords(DataSet ds)' Are you familiar with the term `SCOPE` make your variable names more meaningful also very sloppy in nature

Comment: Well I suspect `ds0` is null, a debugger would tell you, I assume you are using Visual Studio which has a brilliant debugger. Use it! It will save you even thinking about typing a question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ds0 is a local variable inside your BtnLogin_Click function. For a quick fix, you could have NavigateRecords accept a DataSet as an argument and return a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

You face this error because you haven't assigned any values to your **dataset** or your dataset hasn't got any **tables** or your table doesn't have any **rows**. so before writing the below line

```
ds0.Tables["own"].Rows[0];
```

you need to check

```
if(ds0!=null && ds0.Tables.Contains("own") && ds0.Tables["own"].Rows.Length >  0)
{
     //your code
}
```

Comment: this is also a scope issue he has no access to `DataSet ds` once he calls `Navigate` Method..

Comment: @DJKRAZE i guess not, because i can't see the ds definition in the login_click method